# Can't use Objective-c @try @catch @finally syntax at ANE?

Tags: objective-c

I write an ios library and named libDemo.a. When I linked libDemo.a with ANE (Adobe Native Extension) and package the .ane file to .ipa file, the linker fails with some error:

```
Undefined symbols:

  "_objc_terminate", referenced from:
```

The error raised from an objective-c source file (named it Demo.m), and the failed function has some code like this:

```
@try{
...
}
@finally{
...
}
```

When I comment the @try and @finally line, the linker returned with success code.

So, maybe can't use @try @catch syntax when the library will be used at ANE environments?

Comment: C/C++/Obj C Exception handling does not work in iOS ANE. It is a known issue. This is answer from adobe http://forums.adobe.com/message/4221668 .

Comment: The problem has been solved. With the Flash Builder 4.0(AIR 3.1),I add the platformsdk option when to package the ipa file like this: <pre> -platformsdk "${IPHONE_SDK}" "${IPHONE_SDK}" </pre>